# Electric potential / infinity is not the 0 reference

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, coordinate-systems, voltage

Let's say we have a charged sphere with radius $r$. Usually, the way we define its potential is $V = kQ/r$. In this way, we have defined its potential with infinity as the zero reference point. Let's say I want to change the reference point of 0, so now that reference point is at a distance r(a) from its center. How would we write the equation for V?

Comment: All you can do to the expression for $V$ is add or subtract a constant. You can figure out what that constant needs to be to make the potential be zero at whatever you radius you want.

Comment: The "*electric potential* [of] *infinity is not* [at] *the $0$ reference*" - This is impossible. No matter what you do, the infinite potential would remain at the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing reference points amounts to a shifting the potential by a constant.  If you want

$$V(r) = \frac{kQ}{r} + C$$
to be equal to zero at $r=r_a$, then

$$V(r_a) = \frac{kQ}{r_a} + C = 0 \implies C = -\frac{kQ}{r_a}$$
and so

$$V(r) = \frac{kQ}{r} - \frac{kQ}{r_a} = kQ \left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r_a}\right)$$